# Different ways to show intention to do something

Tags: grammar, word-choice

How can one say "I am going to", express intention to do something in the future. I know some expressions such as:

> たいと思う    - 　I'm going to/ I want to
>
> ましょう    - I will/ Why don't I
>
> しようと思う　- I think I will
>
> しようとする - I'll try to
>
> するところ - I'm about to
>
> つもり - I plan to
>
> する予定がある - I have plans to
>
> する気がある - I feel like
>
> ことにする  - decide to
>
> まいとする　- I'll try not to
>
> まいと思う - I think I won't

Do I understand what they mean correctly? Which are better to use when? What is the difference between similar expressions (予定　and　つもり) ?

Comment: I think you might be better off breaking up this question into smaller (slightly more focused?) questions. :)  In general, the meanings seem correct (except, I'm not quite sure about that しょうと思う usage...) but anyway, if the question is broken up, it can generally help for getting answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your definitions were mostly OK I think.

I'm not an expert on grammar, so take this as a temporal answer until other people answer, but my interpretations thus far are...:

- `～たいと思う` means "I think I'd like to...":

  > 本を読みたいと思う "I think I'd like to read a book"
- `～ましょう` means "let's do..." (polite form):

  > 本を読みましょう "Let's read a book"
- `～しようと思う` means "I think I'll...":

  > 本を読もうと思う "I think I'll read a book"
- `～しようとする` means "I'll try to..." as you said:

  > 本を読もうとする "I'll try to read a book"
- `～するところ` means "I'm about to..."/"I'm at the point of..." or "place for (do)ing...":

  > 本を読むところ "I'm about to read a book" or "place for reading books"
- `～つもり` means "I intend to", slightly less formal than `～予定がある` I think and is less likely to be used in business etc:

  > 本を読むつもりだ "I intend to read a book"
- `～する予定がある` "I have plans to" as stated:

  > 本を読む予定がある "I have plans to read a book"
- `～する気がある` "I am of a mind to":

  > 本を読む気がある "I am of a mind to read a book"
- I think `～ことにする` translates differently depending on the context, but that it generally means "(will) go with (do)ing...":

  > 今週こそは本を読むことにする "I will go with reading a book this week"

I'm not sure about `～まいとする` and `～まいと思う`. I think the difference between `～予定がある` and `～つもり` might need it's own question.

Comment: I thought ～たいと思う was "I think I want to.."

Comment: @dotnetN00b I think both "I think I want to..." and "I think I would like to..." would work, but I'm not sure. [Space ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86/UTF-8/) defines it as "be inclined to" among other definitions.

Comment: My dictionary states that ~まいと思う is the negative form of ~ようと思う