# Japanese sentence that needs translation

Tags: translation

I'll just write the sentence here and hope I get some good translations. Always thankful. :)

"僕がしたいって聞いた事をこんなにも叶えてくれようとしてくれてるんだもん"

(My rough translation): I want to do (or things I want to do) that I asked for and getting to (try to)??? fulfill things like this what the heck???

I understand the basic idea of what is being said, but I have a few specific worries.

1. したいって聞いたこと; Is he talking about things he want or things he asked others that he wanted to do?
2. こんなにも; Never quite understood how nimo works. . .
3. (Hardest part) かなえてくれようとしてくれてるんだもん; Here my head just goes crazy and I see a hundred rules popping up everywhere. This is probably the hardest segment of them all. The others are just minor issues, while this one is the main problem I have with this sentence.

Good luck and thanks in advance. :_=)

Answer (score 2):

- 僕がしたいって聞いたこと: ＝僕が「したい」と聞いたこと. Hmm this part is ambiguous because 聞く can mean both *to ask* and *to hear*. Either "the requests I heard from others" (someone else said したい) or "the things I asked for" (僕 himself said したい). Since you said it's in porn, perhaps this means the latter, but only you can determine which is correct.
- こんなにも: こんなに ("like this") + も (intensifier) → "this much"

叶えてくれようとしてくれてるんだもん is a colloquialism for 叶えてくれようとしてくれて**い**る**の**だも**の**. Yes lots of grammatical aspects are involved, so please refer to the links below.

- 叶えて: the te-form of 叶える ("fulfill", "grant")
- くれよう: the volitional form of the [subsidiary verb くれる](http://maggiesensei.com/2010/02/22/%EF%BC%88%E3%80%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%EF%BC%89%E3%81%82%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%EF%BC%8B%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%EF%BC%8B%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%86-shite-ageru%EF%BC%8Bkureru%EF%BC%8Bmorau/). ("for me")
- [～ようとする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5005/5010): to try to do ～ ("to try to do ～ for me")
- ～ようとして: the te-form of the above ("trying to do ～ for me")
- くれて: the te-form of the subsidiary verb くれる
- る/いる: the subsidiary verb denoting [an action in progress](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010) ("is doing")
- んだもん/のだもの: "It's because ...", "Coz..."

  - ん/の: [explanatory-no](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)
  - だ: the copula ("be")
  - もん/もの: a sentence-end particle. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2240/5010) and [this](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE-mono/).

So put together, the sentence probably means "Cos you're trying to fulfill my wishes this much for me." It may mean "Cos you're trying to fulfill their wishes, which I heard from them, this much for me."

This sentence is not very well-written. You should not repeat くれる like this. This sentence should be either one of the followings:

- ～叶えようとしてくれてるんだもん Cos you're trying to fulfill for me...
- ～叶えてくれようとしてるんだもん Cos you're trying to fulfill for me...

Comment: I feel like the sentence would become more like "(I feel this way) Because they are trying to fulfil (for me) the things that I told them I wanted, I . . ."

Comment: Ah, yes, that's totally possible if this guy is talking about someone else. That's why we always say the context is needed :)